# Error: The method 'execute' isn't defined for the class 'Type'

Tags: flutter, dart

> The method 'execute' isn't defined for the type 'Type'

How can I solve the error I get above?

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

class LiteDb {

static Database? _db;

Future<Database?> get getInstance async {
if (_db == null) {
_db = await instance();
return _db;
else {
return _db;
    }
  }
Future<void> addSalaryColumn() async {
final db = await Database;
await db.execute(
        "ALTER TABLE PERSON ADD COLUMN salary INTEGER DEFAULT 0"
    );
  }

instance() async {
Get a location using getDatabasesPath
var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
String path = join(databasesPath, 'lite_sql.db');

open the database
Database database = await openDatabase(path, version: 2,
onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
When creating the db, create the table
await db.execute(

CREATE TABLE PERSON (id INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT NOT NULL, age INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT (id INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, PERSON_ID INTEGER NOT  NULL, ACCOUNT INTEGER NOT NULL, VALUE REAL);
              ''');
print('Text Database has been created');
        },

onUpgrade: (Database db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) async {
if (newVersion >= 2) {
await db.execute('''
ALTER TABLE PERSON ADD COLUMN salary REAL NULL
            ''');
          }
        }

    );
print(' Database connected');
return database;
  }

inquiry(String sqlTxt) async {
Database? db = await getInstance;
Get the records
List<Map> list = await db!.rawQuery(sqlTxt);
return list;
  }

insert(String sqlTxt) async {
Database? db = await getInstance;
Insert some record
int count = await db!.rawInsert(sqlTxt);
return count;
  }

update(String sqlTxt) async {
Database? db = await getInstance;
Update some record
int count = await db!.rawUpdate(sqlTxt);
return count;
  }

delete(String sqlTxt) async {
Database? db = await getInstance;
Delete some record
int count = await db!.rawDelete(sqlTxt);
return count;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't share screenshots or images of the code. Kindly update your question properly with [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and what you have tried so far

Comment: use tripple back tick ( ``` ) to differentiate your code from other texts

Comment: `final db = await Database;` is wrong; `Database` is the name of some class, so when you later do `db.execute()`, you're attempting to call `execute()` on an instance of a `Type` object.  Presumably you want to `await` some asynchronous function call that ultimately returns an *instance* of a `Database`.